# Unexpected result while looping through pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I load content of a csv to a dataframe.

```
data = pd.read_csv("census.csv")
```

Then I check data size

```
print( data.size) --> 633108
```

Then I loop through DataFrame

```
counter = 0
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    counter += 1
```

Then I check the counter and datasize again.

```
print( counter) --> 45222
print( data.size) --> 633108
```

They sould be same, I could not understand why they are not same. I would appriciate any help.

Comment: Think `counter` should be `data.shape[0]` because you are iterating through its rows.

Comment: `data.shape` will return rows x columns.

Comment: yes, there are 13 columns + 1 index. 14x45222 = 633108. Thanks a lot for these fast responses. Both answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` isn't the correct attribute to use.  `size` is the total number of elements.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3, 4)))
df.size

12
```

`size` will coincidentally be correct if there is only one column

```
df.iloc[:, [0]].size

3
```

Instead, use `df.shape[0]` to get the number of rows

```
df.shape[0]

3
```

Or

```
len(df)

3
```

I prefer `len(df)` because it is ever so slightly quicker access than `df.shape[0]`

```
%timeit df.shape[0]
%timeit len(df)

1.58 µs ± 47.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
916 ns ± 21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

You can replicate this for the 2nd dimension with `len(df.columns)`

```
%timeit df.shape[1]
%timeit len(df.columns)

1.65 µs ± 67.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
679 ns ± 34.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

For grabbing the shape tuple, it's equivalent to grabbing both `len` of `df.index` and `df.column`.  Avoid going to `values` for it's `shape` attribute as the call to form the `values` array is too much overhead.  Unless of course you need that array for something else.

```
%timeit df.shape
%timeit df.values.shape
%timeit len(df), len(df.columns)

1.58 µs ± 75.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
5.78 µs ± 198 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1.65 µs ± 35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```